# How to get better control over connection pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-pooling

I've been getting this error recently, after several reloads of the same page:

*System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached*

So I am thinking there must be some queries or calls in the app I used incorrectly that causes them not to release the connection. Is there any tools out there that allows me to somehow peek into the pool to see who is hanging on to what?

Comment: I suppose you are talking about SQL connections. Are you closing your connections properly? With `using(SQlConnection...){...}`?

Comment: Albin, that is it, not all connection were wrapped in "usings" so when the connection happens in a loop, it runs out quickly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a timeout property on your connection object that you can change. This will change the time it waits to get a connection, there's also a command timeout which controls how long it waits until the command times out once it is running (but the first one sounds like what you need) [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) (anything that inherits from DBConnection should have this if you arn't using sql server).

Have a [look here too](https://web.archive.org/web/20160221084422/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/angelsb/archive/2004/08/25/220333.aspx), might help :)